# Missing required parameter for [Route: building.floors] [URI: building/{building}/floors]

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I need your help. How can I write in the following href using route?

I have the following route:

`Route::get('/building/{building}/floors', [BuildingController::class, 'floors'])->name('building.floors');`

In the **view** I have:

`<td><a href="{{URL::to('/building/' . $building->id . '/floors') }}" class="link-primary">{{ $building->floors }}</a></td>`

I tried to write it in the following way

`<td><a href="{{route('building.floors' , ['id' => $building->id])}}" class="link-primary">{{ $building->floors }}</a></td>`

but I get the error **Missing required parameter for [Route: building.floors] [URI: building/{building}/floors]**.

Can anyone kindly help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess but should `['id' => $building->id]` be `['building' => $building->id]` (because `building` is the name of the variable in the route)?

Comment: that was the problem. Instead of id I have to put building

Answer (score 0):

@Sarah you need to understand the error.

Always remember this
`Route::get('/building/{building}/floors', [BuildingController::class, 'floors'])->name('building.floors');`
here `{building}` is your dynamic parameter name, thus you need to pass the same parameter `{building}` in your blade anywhere you use this route.

we will use id if the route is `Route::get('/building/{id}/floors', [BuildingController::class, 'floors'])->name('building.floors');` because we are passing `{id}` as a dynamic parameter.

In this code `/building/{building}/floors` if your parameter buidling is representing building id than you must use a proper and meaningfull parameter name like `{building_id}` in route file and pass `['building_id' => $building->id]` as building represent your class/object name and you are trying to pass it's property `id` as a parameter. This help to avoid confusions also other developer find it easy to read and work on the same.